# I am not able to upload image in directory using Php

Tags: php

My Code

```
$folder="images/";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['simage']['tmp_name'],"$folder".$_FILES['simage']['name']);
```

`$_FILES['simage']` is the file.
The image is not moved to the directory.

Form code

```
<form  class="form-horizontal" id="register" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Input field

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" name="simage"/>
```

Comment: post error log here

Comment: also post you html form

Comment: _Note:_ You don't need to wrap variables in quotes to print them.

Comment: What you need to do is some basic debugging. Check the servers error log for errors. Do you have sufficient permissions to write the the output path? Is the output path even valid? If the folder `images/` is in the same folder your script, use absolute paths instead: `$folder = __DIR__ . '/images/'`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Where is OP printing a variable?

Comment: @Toastrackenigma - Printing/concatenating... same thing: `"$folder".$_FILES['simage']['name']`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson That's concatenating, not printing. But you have a perfectly valid point, that is definitely not the way to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but my problem is solved by giving full path of the directory $folder= "/var/www/html/completelogin/images/";